# Value 0% and 100% of keyframes if they are not specified

Tags: css

If i have this css code :

```
keyframes cyclefive {

   76% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   80% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }


 }
```

what values will have 0% and 100% ?

I suppose they will have both `{ top: 0px; opacity: 1;  }`.
Or `0%` will have `0% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }`

Comment: i test it of course and it's work like i want but i want a valid rule to use it all time not just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specifying the **from** (0%) and **to** (100%) keyframes is an [invalid declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

> In order for a keyframe list to be valid, it must include rules for at
>   least the times 0% (or from) and 100% (or to) (that is, the starting
>   and ending states of the animation). If both of these time offsets
>   aren't specified, the keyframe declaration is invalid and can't be
>   used for animation.

That said, I'd also recommend [reading this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/animation-keyframe-gotcha/)

> If 0% and 100% keyframe values arent specified the browser will typically
>   construct them based on the computed values of the properties being
>   animated.

Comment: thanks @SW4 it really help your article. some users instead of helping me with good article to understand they answer me with non constructive question, may be they don't have the answer but it will be nice if they do nothing. this forum need man like you who understand newbie like us thanks again man.